# Remove action in an existing plugin class via another plugin

Tags: plugins, woothemes

I am trying to remove an action within an existing WooThemes Sensei Class

`global $woothemes_sensei;
        remove_action( 'sensei_single_course_modules_before', array( $woothemes_sensei->modules, 'course_modules_title' ),20 );
        remove_action( 'sensei_single_course_modules_content', array( $woothemes_sensei->modules, 'course_module_content' ),30 );`

I am not sure what I am doing wrong? I think I am calling the correct class with the global variable. And the labels are correct? I've tried various priorities.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1. You must wrap the remove functions in a function and attach it to a hook, before the action in question has been run.
2. `$this` has no context here. it only has context inside a class
3. `remove_action` must have the exact same priority as the `add_action` that you are trying to remove
4. The `course-modules.php` template says exactly how the `course_modules_title` action is being added

> ```
> /**
>  * Hook runs inside single-course/course-modules.php
>  *
>  * It runs before the modules are shown. This hook fires on the single course page,but only if the course has modules.
>  *
>  * @since 1.8.0
>  *
>  * @hooked Sensei()->modules->course_modules_title - 20
>  */
> do_action('sensei_single_course_modules_before');
> ```

Sensei does not appear to be using a global and the modules class is accessed via `Sensei()->modules` as hinted at in the template. Therefore something like the following should remove your actions:

```
function so_31590319_remove_sensei_actions(){
    remove_action('sensei_single_course_modules_before',array( Sensei()->modules,'course_modules_title' ), 20);
    remove_action('sensei_single_course_modules_content', array( Sensei()->modules,'course_module_content' ), 20);
}
add_action( 'sensei_single_course_modules_before', 'so_31590319_remove_sensei_actions', 10 );
```